# Error:Execution failed for task ':projectName:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources'. > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Tags: android

I use the android studio import lib, appeared the following error，IOS_Dialog_Library is ProjectName，Messages Gradle Build:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:IOS_Dialog_Library:generateDebugSources,
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:generateDebugAndroidTestSources,
>   :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:checkDebugManifest
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:compileLint :IOS_Dialog_Library:copyDebugLint
>   UP-TO-DATE :IOS_Dialog_Library:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug
>   UP-TO-DATE :IOS_Dialog_Library:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
>   UP-TO-DATE :IOS_Dialog_Library:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :IOS_Dialog_Library:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources AAPT err(Facade for
>   98288211): libpng error: Not a PNG file Error:Execution failed for
>   task ':IOS_Dialog_Library:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources'.
>
> > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 1.462 secs Information:1 error
> >     Information:0 warnings Information:See complete output in console

I got a lot of places did not find this problem, need your help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

From bug, [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=163378) it is said that this can happen when using the Gradle Tools v1.1.0. After updating to v1.1.3, this has not happened anymore

Comment: I'm using Gradle Tools is the latest version 2.0.0 - alpha3, don't know why will appear this problem

Comment: dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }